# Sql Server: Any way to group records by date based on the dates of other records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table that has events in it and I need to find duplicate events. The problem is that events that take place withing 1 second of each other are considered duplicates. So if my table has these values

```
id | var1 | var2 | var3 | date
1  | 1    | 2    | 3    | 2001-01-01 01:01:01.456
2  | 1    | 2    | 3    | 2001-01-01 01:01:02.234
3  | 1    | 2    | 3    | 2001-01-01 01:01:04.789
```

records 1 and 2 are considered duplicates because they are within one second, but 3 is not because it's more than one second after 2.

Is there any way to write a query that only selects the first record in a series of duplicates?

EDIT: There may also be rows that are not duplicated that will need to be captured. Id is the primary key of the table and is not used in the matching criteria; it's just there for clarification.

Comment: what if there are three record within a second of each other... only keep 1? and is ID just a PK, meaning that var1, var2, and var3 should be considered for duplicates? i.e. if they aren't the same, then it isn't a duplicate?

Comment: @scsimon Yes. All records where var1, 2, and 3 are the same and date is within 1 second, only 1 record should be kept. Doesn't matter if there are 2 or 200 in that range. Id is a PK.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @RossD. I just edited my answer and i *thin* it should work in all instances. let me know if it doesn't. I left it in multiple cte's for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that seems like it should work for you.

Some assumptions:

1. I assume duplicate is an actual row duplicate excluding ID, based on the 1 second clause you provided. If this is not the case... remove the partition by part of the `row_number()` window function and it will change the behavior
2. This removes recursive duplicates. That is, if 3,4, or even 15 rows are within a second of each other, it keeps 1.
3. This should work regardless if the first row or last row is a duplicate

Here's the code. Uncomment out the two rows in the table to see the changes

```
declare @table table(id int, var1 int, var2 int, var3 int, date datetime2)
insert into @table
values
--(0,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 00:01:01.456'), 

(1,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 01:01:01.456'), --dupe of 1/2/3
(2,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 01:01:02.214'), --dupe of 1/2/3
(3,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 01:01:02.234'), --dupe of 1/2/3
(4,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 01:01:02.244'), --dupe of 1/2/3

(5,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 01:01:04.789'), --dupe of 4/5
(6,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 01:01:04.989'), --dupe of 4/5

--(7,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 01:01:06.789'), --dupe of 6/7
(8,1,2,3,'2001-01-01 01:01:06.799') --dupe of 6/7

--apply the sequence
;with cte as(
select 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by var1, var2, var3 order by date) as RN  --just in case... change this to just order by id, date if need be and remove the partition
from 
    @table),

--get first / most of the batch to remove
cte2 as(
select
    c1.*
    ,c2.RN as RowsToRemove
from cte c1
left join
    cte c2 on c1.RN < c2.rn  and 
    datediff(second,c1.date,c2.date) < 1),


--remove the rows identified in the above cte
cte3 as(
select distinct
    ID, 
    var1,
    var2,
    var3,
    date,
    RN
from cte2
where 
    RN not in (select distinct isnull(RowsToRemove,0) from cte2)),

--add another sequence. This is necessary for first/last row check for duplicate
cte4 as(
select
    f.*,
    row_number() over (partition by var1, var2, var3 order by date) RN2
from 
    cte3 f)

--return the results
select 
    f.ID, 
    f.var1,
    f.var2,
    f.var3,
    f.date
from 
    cte4 f
left join
    cte4 d on d.RN = f.RN - 1
where isnull(datediff(second,d.date,f.date),500) > 1
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----+------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| ID | var1 | var2 | var3 |            date             |
+----+------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 |    1 |    2 |    3 | 2001-01-01 01:01:01.4560000 |
|  5 |    1 |    2 |    3 | 2001-01-01 01:01:04.7890000 |
|  8 |    1 |    2 |    3 | 2001-01-01 01:01:06.7990000 |
+----+------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Lag is one possible solution, something like this:

```
select * from (
select *, lag(date,1) over(order by date) previoustime from yourtable
) x
where datediff(second,previoustime,date)<1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select T1.date,... from MyTable T1
left outer join MyTable T2 on cast(T1.date as date) = cast(T2.date as date) and 
datediff(second,T1.date,T2.date)<=1
group by cast(T1.date as date)
```